# When i export an illustrator picture/file

Tags: adobe-illustrator

when I want to save a illustrator cs5 document to print after i export it as png but when I am ready to export it previews the document and it's not a full page size, it shows the document in the middle and a while outline or background. I need my document to print in the entire page. Please help thanks

Comment: Why export as PNG? Is the document set up tot he size of the printed sheet?

Answer (score 1):

To export images to their designed size, you must check the box "Use Artboards" in the Export dialog. That will crop the image to the size of the artboard. If it still produces an image that has white margins, you'll have to adjust the artboard size to be the size of the cropping you want in the Document Setup and Edit Artboards.

If, in your case I presume, there is only one artboard, you'll just then have to push Export. If you have made multiple artboards (ie. pages), you might want to select the number of the artboard you only want to export. To find out the artboard number, turn on the Artboards window. The number of the artboard is the list order index, not the number in the artboard name (eg. "Artboard 1" might be second in the list and is therefore artboard number 2).

All the exported files (even if there's only one) are named as [Document name]-[Artboard number].

You'll might also want to consider using the Slice tool, if you need to export many separate png's. The slices export to their individual files using the Save for Web feature, which automatically only export the slices, nothing else, if you have added at least one.

Answer (score 0):

The preview will show you your entire document at its correct size, PLUS anything else you might have on the artboard. If you just want to see your document, then you will need to check on every layer to see if there is anything on the artboard. Sometimes it's just a stray point that wasn't deleted and doesn't show, sometimes it's something that is hidden for another reason.

Once the artboard is clear you will see things the way you expect them to be.

Alternatively, export as is and then crop the document back to your target size in Photoshop.